# Как попросить sqlalchemy возвращать сырые, raw данные в результате запросов к БД?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql

Привет всем! Если в sqlalchemy сделать какую-либо выборку, в которой к примеру, будет существовать поле с типом DATETIME, sqlalchemy автоматически преобразует значение этого поля в объект DateTime. Все это, конечно, хорошо, но как сделать так, чтобы результаты запросов возвращались в обычном, строковом виде?

Answer (score 2):

Это конечно не прямой ответ на вопрос, но что мешает представить полученную дату в нужном формате самому?

```
myDate.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

Comment: Такой вариант не подходит, потому что везде, где производятся запросы, придется втыкать костыли с проверкой типов данных

Comment: А если преобразовывать в текст в sql-запросе?

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете использовать свой тип (http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/custom_types.html#augmenting-existing-types) :

```
class StrDateTime(TypeDecorator):
    impl = types.DateTime

    def process_result_value(self, value, dialect):
       if value is not None:
           value = str(value)
       return value
```

И дальше использовать его

`datetime_column = Column('datetime_column', StrDateTime)`